# The argumnet type 'Null Funcion(DataSnapshot)' cnt be assigned to the parameter type 'Future Or <dynamic> Function(DataBaseEvent)'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have this function that is giving me an error.

the `getCurrentOnLineUserInfo` function is trying to get read data from the Firebase Database of the current user that is logged in.

> The argument type 'Null Funcion(DataSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter of type 'Future Or  Function(DataBaseEvent)'

I am following a year-old tutorial, so the issue might be the code is old. I might need new syntax or something.

```
static void getCurrentOnLineUserInfo() async {
    firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String userId = firebaseUser!.uid;
    DatabaseReference reference =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("user").child(userId);

    print("getCurrentOnLineUser info executed!");

    print('${firebaseUser!.email}${firebaseUser!.displayName}');
    
    // errors below this

    reference.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (dataSnapShot!.value != null) {
        userCurrentInfo = Users.fromSnapshot(dataSnapshot);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

and here is my class that is assigning data. This class is giving no errors

```
class Users {
  String? id;
  String? email;
  String? phone;
  String? name;

  Users({this.id, this.email, this.phone, this.name});

  Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    id = dataSnapshot.key!;

    var data = dataSnapshot.value as Map?;

    if (data != null) {
      email = data?["email"];
      name = data?["name"];
      phone = data?["phone"];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have an inkling `'Null Funcion(DataSnapshot)` is not copied verbatim.

Answer (score 7):

The `once` method returns a `DatabaseEvent`, not a `DataSnapshot`. `DatabaseEvent` is a class that encapsulates a `DataSnapshot` **AND** a `DatabaseEventType`, to extract the snapshot, you must use `DatabaseEvent.snapshot`:

```
reference.once().then((event) {
  final dataSnapshot = event.snapshot;
  if (dataSnapShot!.value != null) {
    userCurrentInfo = Users.fromSnapshot(dataSnapshot);
  }
});
```

Here is another solution I think might do what you want:

```
// async methods should return a future
static Future<void> getCurrentOnLineUserInfo() async {
    firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    String userId = firebaseUser!.uid;
    DatabaseReference reference =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("user").child(userId);

    final snapshot = await reference.get(); // you should use await on async methods
    if (snapshot!.value != null) {
      userCurrentInfo = Users.fromSnapshot(snapshot);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help.. error is gone but still not reading data

Comment: still getting error userCurrentInfo is null...

Comment: @mobdev991 I am sorry, I am not knowledgable on realtime database, thus my answer can only come from the little knowledge I have and from reading the docs, regardless, I have edited my answer to show a different possible solution, could you check if that one works?

Answer (score 1):

I was following the same old tutorial you mentioned, the @mobdev991 answer is correct and i think the reason why you don't receive data is the class where you are assigning data try this

```
class Users {
  String? id;
  String? email;
  String? name;
  String? phone;

  Users({this.id, this.email, this.name, this.phone});


  Users.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    id = dataSnapshot.key;
    email = (dataSnapshot.child("email").value.toString());
    name =  (dataSnapshot.child("name").value.toString());
    phone =  (dataSnapshot.child("phone").value.toString());
  }
}
```