# firebase_database - error after flutter migration - DataSnapshot syntax

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I used this code bevor migration

```
  void initState() {
    DatabaseReference db;
    db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("likes");
    db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key, values) {
        likeList.add(values["check"]);
        print(likeList);
      });
    });
  }
```

after "dart pub upgrade --null-safety" I get the Error:

```
The argument type 'Null Function(DataSnapshot)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<dynamic> Function(DatabaseEvent)
```

I can't find anything in the changelos on pub.dev how to use DataSnapshot in this case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585172/the-argumnet-type-null-funciondatasnapshot-cnt-be-assigned-to-the-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `DataSnapshot`, you should put `DatabaseEvent` within the then

```
  void initState() {
    DatabaseReference db;
    db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child("likes");
    db.once().then((DatabaseEvent databaseEvent) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = databaseEvent.snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key, values) {
        likeList.add(values["check"]);
        print(likeList);
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: thx, but now I get the new error: The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'DatabaseEvent'

Comment: @Bernhard I have updated the answer. Do check it out and let me know!

Comment: yes works, great thanks